# How in decrease and increase the margin on scroll

Tags: javascript, margin

I want to write javascript code to move my text upward by decrease the margin-top (default is 0) when the window is scrolled up. But when I scroll down, the margin-top of my text doesn't equal 0. Please Help

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pagna/hrrcmry2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="h">
    <div id="t">Hello</div>
    <div id="content"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#h {
    background:green;
    width:550px;
    height:200px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    padding:50px 0 0 100px;
}
#t {
    font-size:40px;
    color:white;
}
#content {
    background:blue;
    width:550px;
    height:700px;
    margin:200px 0;
    position:relative;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var pos = 0;
var el = document.getElementById("t");
var m = 0;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    if (window.pageYOffset > pos) {
        m -= 1;
        el.style.marginTop = m + "px";
    } else {
        m += 1;
        el.style.marginTop = m + "px";
    }
    pos = window.pageYOffset;
}, false);
```

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: would you like to explain why exactly you want to change text margin on page scroll? the text will go up anyway, whats your logic?

Comment: Do u know how to post jsfiddle link here since I'm a newer here?  then i can show you my code

Comment: if it says that it needs to be followed by code, simply add your code to the question alongside the fiddle link

Comment: Here is all my code, Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to add pixel by pixel. you can just set the text margin directly from the scrollTop:

```
var pos = 0;
var el = document.getElementById("t");
var m = 0;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    el.style.marginTop = -window.pageYOffset/2 + "px";
    pos = window.pageYOffset;
}, false);
```

<kbd>**[Fixed Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/hrrcmry2/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: you are most welcomed :) please consider accepting my answer if it helped. (green V on the left)

Comment: The jsfiddle link is broken. please fix